# Flip in Fragment android view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to do front and back page for every fragment in view pager. Front page is always shown. If flip button pressed back side should view.  Need to do dice animation for that filp. How can i achieve that in android.

Comment: i think the following is what you need: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May it will help you
[ClickHere](https://github.com/balesz/android-tutorial-CardFlipAnimation)